# longitude and latitude limiting the location

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I specify a zone of locations using longitude and latitude using Objective-C?

Comment: We really need more context than this to answer this question. Do you really just mean how to store a series of sets of lat/long coordinates?

Comment: A square zone?  Circular?  Arbitrary?

Comment: semi circular ie the the front circular location not interested of the back location hope u can imagine it.                        inside and outside of it it there are locations so i want to take the inside of the semi circular ?

Answer (score 1):

So, from your comments...a semi-circle? You could specify that using a radius and degree value indicating the bearing of the line that bisects the circle.

To test whether a point is in the zone, you would test in two parts:

1. Is the distance between the two points smaller than the radius?
2. Is the bearing of the point to the origin within the specified 180 degrees of the semi-circle?

That's about as well as I can figure it without some more detail.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use locationManager to somehow determine my current location's heading and compare it to another location on the map to see if the location on the map falls within the semi circle of my current location.

Comment: specifically I am referring to comparing the angle.  So the second point of your algorithm.  Any tips would be helpful